# Ajax requests, pages, and Code to figure data range for diff. cats

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay, So I will get a little more specific (since my last question).

Basically, I have a pagination page - and there are three display categories BUT only 50 items display per pagination page. So, you could get all of a single category taking up a page, or a combination of different categories - but they can't exceed 50 items per page. Once a new category is reached, a header displays, then the associated items. I am having trouble figuring out the math to append to the ajax call to request each of the categories. For example, lets say you search for *linen*. And lets say you get back a total of 329 matches spread across the three categories as shown below. Now, I will be handed back some *data* so I will know certain things up front even though I will only query 50 items at a time.

A. Search for *linen* :

**Base data**

```
Total Items: 129
Category1 has 111 items
Category2 has 101 items
Category3 has 17 items
```

so, on **page 1** you would see:

```
CATEGORY 1 HEADER
... list of the 50 items ...
```

B. User clicks "next"
(since we are still in the category 1 threshold), we'd get the second set of 50.

**Page 2:**

```
CATEGORY 1 HEADER
List of next 50 items
```

C. USER clicks "next"
(we broke category 1 total, so now we reach into category 2).

**Page 3:**

```
CATEGORY 1 HEADER
List of 11 items

CATEGORY 2 HEADER
List of 39 category 2 items
```

etc..

The issue I am having, that without doing a ton of if/else/||/&& etc.. is there a nifty algorithm that will give me ranges so on the "next" page click I can have ajax params request ranged for the backend.

ie.. so for the third next page click - (has both category1 and category 2, as shown above).
In a perfect world my Ajax would fire two calls, one for category1 and one for category 2, like so. Of course, if the list of 50 spanned all three cats in full, then three calls would be made.

```
/category1?rows=11&start=101
/category2?rows=39&start=1
```

something like that. So I know I want 11 items from first ajax call with the start of 101. The backend, I assume, will know the range is 101-111 etc..

I hope I am succinct enough here to supply my needs. The solution seems very mathish.

I was working along the lines of, just penciling things...

(category1 - (max x (currPage - 1)) / max >= 1 --> request 50 category 1 if true;

(category1 - (max x (currPage - 1)) / max < 1 --> request the Modulus amount and then start into category2

We use jquery.

Comment: this is all still pretty abstract and hard to follow without being able to see some data, and the UI. Perhaps you could create a simplified html demo with some sample data to work with as well

Comment: @charlietfl This doesn't look particularly abstract, and there is sample data in the example.  The question looks pretty straightforward.  As to a solution... let me see...

Comment: @ScottSauyet go ahead and generate an answer then

Comment: I don't really have "data" per see', but I believe Scott has the idea of it. Its just that I have three cats and they can contain "n" amount of data. Per page I can dispaly 50 items. And each category must be exhausted in display before I can display more, BUT yes - I could theoretically display all of it on one page if the total was 50 or less items. 

My confusion is creating an algorithm/logic that is clean without getting into endless 'else if' statements that I can create params for Ajax calls. I was hoping hose more versed in math/algorithms might have a better understanding of my needs.

Comment: to be honest...the UI doesn't sound as user friendly as it could be. Why wade through multiple pages to find a category? This is part of why I suggest the limited info is still not a lot to go on. Also, knowing data structure would be a huge help. It's very difficult to help with counters, create local arrays etc without knowing what data looks like...as opposed to what data might contain. Understanding more about UI would be help also

Comment: I agree - but this is an issue on the backend. We currently frontload all the data and its fine. BUT, they are changing up the backend and based on some timeframe of requesting data and returning it, they now want ONLY a query of 50 returns, rather than the hundreds I can do now. So, I agree its a bad user experience - but architecturely, they don't care - they want it to be fast and thus will only throw back 50 at a time. But truth be told, category2 and category3 are not "that important". They are sorta considered peripheral matches.

Comment: The data itself is not that important because they are list items. The return could be strings... the UI isn't that important. Well, it is if I use only Prev | Next or pagination like so Prev 1 | 2 | 3 | 4|5 | 6 etc... Next , but I believe the algorithm would  allow for dynamism like that.. prev next would allow for a counter of 1 or minus 1. The pagination would be the page num clicked times 50 and work it in like that. Perhaps I am not being succinct enough.

Comment: @charlietfl - ok, done.  Interesting problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is available at http://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/eKApZ/.

The basic idea is this:

```
var createCategoryRangesForPage = (function() {
    var ranges = function(itemCounts) {
        var total = 0;
        var indices = [0].concat(jQuery.map(itemCounts, function(item) {
            return total = total + item.count;
        }));
        var result = function(pageNbr, pageSize) {
            var first = pageSize * (pageNbr - 1),
                last = Math.min(first + pageSize, total),
                firstIdx = indices.length - 1,
                lastIdx = indices.length - 1;
            if (first >= total) {return ranges.OUT_OF_BOUNDS;}
            while (indices[firstIdx] > first) {firstIdx--;}
            while (indices[lastIdx] >= last) {lastIdx--;}
            return jQuery.map(new Array(lastIdx - firstIdx + 1), function(item, idx) {
                var index = idx + firstIdx;
                return {
                    name: itemCounts[index].name,
                    start: Math.max(first, indices[index]) - indices[index] + 1,
                    // end: Math.min(last, indices[index + 1]) - indices[index],
                    count: Math.min(last, indices[index + 1]) - Math.max(first, indices[index])
                };
            });
        };
        result.OUT_OF_BOUNDS = ranges.OUT_OF_BOUNDS;
        return result;
    };
    ranges.OUT_OF_BOUNDS = {message: "Out of bounds", toString:function(){return this.message;}};
    return ranges;
}());
```

You could then create a pagination function like this:

```
var catRangesForPage = createCategoryRangesForPage([
    {name:"CATEGORY 1", count: 111},
    {name:"CATEGORY 2", count: 101},
    {name:"CATEGORY 3", count: 17}
]);
```

And call it for, say, page 3, with page size 50, like this:

```
catRangesForPage(3, 50)
```

to get a result that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "name": "CATEGORY 1",
        "start": 101,
        "count": 11
    },
    {
        "name": "CATEGORY 2",
        "start": 1,
        "count": 39
    }
]
```

which you could clearly use to generate your AJAX calls.

If you wanted to, it would be trivial to move the `pageSize` parameter into the initial call.  That's less flexible, but might be slightly easier to use.  To change this, just move the `pageSize` parameter from this line:

```
        var result = function(pageNbr, pageSize) {
```

to this one:

```
    var ranges = function(itemCounts) {
```

(It should probably be the first parameter here, as it might get lost in the shuffle if you pass an object literal for `itemCounts` the way my sample does.)

The other thing to note is that the function returns a signal object named `OUT_OF_BOUNDS` to let you know you've tried to access a page out of range.  That object is namespaced to both the generator function and the function it returns, whichever you find more convenient.

This has not been tested outside the bounds of your initial problem, and I wouldn't be terribly surprised to find boundary issues somewhere with it.

(This does use jQuery, but only for its `map` utility function.  You could use any decent `map` implementation, including the native one in recent browsers.)

Best of luck!

Comment: Wow -- that was awefully nice of you. I will tinker with it tomorrow and see if it is what I need. Based on your output, I believe I can construct some params for the ajax call. I'll just need to test some 0 length cats with it and see if I can work with that - ie. some categories will return empty. Anyways, really appreciate it. -- curious, what books/tutorials have you found that give a good foundation for this sort of problem solving?

Comment: If you have empty categories and you **want** to show the headers, it should just work.  If you don't want to do so, you might need to do some more work by adding another level of indirection, with a variable like `nonEmpties` that is just an array of indices of the nonEmpty elements of the original list, replacing, e.g., `itemCounts[index].name` with `itemCounts[nonEmpties[index]].name`.  I think that would work.

Comment: As to the problem-solving, it's mostly just experience.  I do read a lot, plenty of blogs, but also books.  Some good recommendations are at http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.javascript/msg/687031ab6b5b26e4